# Matching dropped rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that receives two dataframes, one of price data and one of volume data, neatly structured etc.

At some points, the volume will be `NaN` for a majority of the columns due to data error. This will be handled by simply discarding these nan rows.

Inside my function it looks as follows:

```
self.allData = dbfetch.dfcreator(year,mrange).get()
```

where this returns a tuple of two dataframes containing what I just described. What I can do next is then of course to write:

```
self.volFrame = self.allData[0].dropna(thresh=9)
```

where 9 missing observations is the rule for when the data is so bad I want to drop the enire row.

However, my problem is that now I have two mismatched dataframes that need to be the same amount of rows. They are date-indexed by separate columns, which comes from the structure of the SQL-database.

Is there any method for me to tell the other dataframe that if the date-columns don't match between the two, then drop the excess ones in the price-frame. Or something that would achieve the same purpose?

Thanks to Pankaj for giving me the answers which solved my issue. However, I solved the last step in a different manner. If anyone's interested, heres my solution:

```
    allData = dbfetch.dfcreator(year,month).get()
    p = allData[0]; pCols = p.columns
    v = allData[1].dropna(thresh=9); vCols = v.columns      
    df = pd.concat([p, v], axis=1, join_axes=[v.index])
    self.priceData = df[list(pCols)]
    self.volData = df[list(vCols)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pandas ["concat"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) mehtod and join the two dataframes into a new dataframe according to the indices of price dataframe.

```
New_data_frame = pd.concat([df_price, df_volume], axis=1, join_axes=[df_price.index])
```

In the new data_frame, entries of price and volume dataframes will be present according to the indices of price dataframe.

Comment: Is it possible for me to extract a tuple of the column names of each df that I am going to concat such that I can separate this into two separate df's again once I have forced them to have the same index?

Comment: You can use pandas 'isin()' function to extract the column like following:  `df_volume[df_volume['date'].isin(df_price['date'])]`